# Flexbox not working to center a Woocommerce Button

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

i'm trying to center a button in my woocommerce website but without sucess.

Heres what i already tried:

```
margin: auto;
float: none;
display: block;

display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

[image]

I made it work without flexbox but isnt responsive and i need to learn more flexbox.

This is the result using flexbox:

[image: image2]

Can someone help? if needed, this is the website: http://svidro.recifeimage.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using relative positioning combined with CSS transforms instead of flexbox to center the button:

```
position: relative;
/* moves button to the middle of its container */
left: 50%;
/* moves button 50% of its width to the left */
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt knew about this. Working!!

Answer (score 4):

-you should have one `<div>` and inside it your `<button>`
-`<div>` should have this style

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
```

-this is because the content of tag that has

```
justify-content: center;
```

will center only it's **content** 
- in this case you will have `<div>` and it's content is `<button>`

Comment: Bad sides of using a already done wordpress theme :( but thanks the help